# UICC: Can I trust proactive TIMER MANAGEMENT?

Tags: android, ios, smartcard, javacard, sim-card

UICC (SIM card) has no internal clock. If an applet loaded on the SIM card needs to know, whether some time interval has already elapsed, it has to allocate a timer in the device and start it using TIMER MANAGEMENT proactive command.

ETSI standard (102 223 V12.1.0) says:

> "The precision of the returned value cannot be relied upon in all
>   cases due to potential terminal activities"

Does it mean that the timer can fire the desired event even BEFORE it should?

Is there any protection provided by OS against the timer event fraud (an attacker pretending the timer event has been fired)?

Can I trust the timer even in some "serious" security applications, or is it just kind of a toy with a limited real world usage?

Comment: Didn't found any way to use your network time?

Comment: What happen if you started a timer for some moment and before timer expiration mobile got switched off...then there will be no timer expiration event will ocuur you have to check again restart the timer but you will not able to get the remaining time.

Comment: @Abraham Well, the network time seems to be easily hacked. Your envelope solution would be fine, but it needs GSM connection. Timers would work completely network independent. Switching off is not a problem, I just need to be sure some short amount of time already elapsed (it does not matter if the time is longer, I can always restart the timer and try it again).

Comment: @AnuragSharma Switching off is not an issue. I just need to be 100% sure if 5 minutes have elapsed since "something" happened. So I can restart the timer in case of switching off.

Comment: _the network time seems to be easily hacked._ **how?** _it needs GSM connection_ **Yes, you are right.**

Comment: You can trust the timer but be sure the mobile handset is working as it should be.Because some phone dont support Timer functionality you have to check its Terminal Profile

Comment: @Abraham The network time (time synchronized over GSM with no server application) is synchronized in the moment when the phone is logged into the network. The user can change his system time after that, although the phone says it uses the network time.

Comment: @AnuragSharma I checked it and timer functionality seems to be implemented in all major types. The question is if someone could hack the timer by sending the timer event from some evil application (it could send the appropriate APDU through SEEK, for example).

Comment: May we have a short discussion here please(About SIM/USIM development basics)? : http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74693/sim-cards-development

Comment: @vojta yes timer expiration envelope can be send by any APDU tool and your applet will assume it expired even if time period is not completed.

Comment: Can't you send the appreciate APDU concatenated with its encrypted value to prevent sending counterfeit expiration APDU-s by evil applications? I mean the data field of the appreciate APDU for expiration time is consist of two part that the second part is encrypted part of the first part. and only the SIM and vojta's application having the encryption key. more over he can use a counter to prevent replay attacks also. right?

Comment: @Abraham timer expiration envelope will be send by mobile and it will not be encrypted in any way.

Comment: @AnuragSharma By the mobile or by the vojta's application on the phone?

Comment: 1. The timer may be fired after the desired time, because the phone may be busy. But this is far more precise than using poll mechanism.
2. Using timer, poll, or provide local information does not protect your application against fraud. Everything can be replied by terminal unsecuredly.
3. If you would like the time to be secure, perhaps you can send encrypted SMS submit to the network, which the server will count the time and send you envelope SMSPP securedly. Of course, this needs GSM connection.

Comment: @David Could you please post this as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. "The precision of the returned value cannot be relied upon in all cases due to potential terminal activities" means that the timer may be fired after the desired time, because the phone may be busy. But this is far more precise than using poll mechanism.
2. Using timer, poll, or provide local information (date & time) does not protect your application against fraud. Everything can be replied by terminal unsecuredly.
3. If you would like the time to be secured, perhaps you can send encrypted SMS submit to the network, which the server will count the time and send you envelope SMSPP securedly. Of course, this needs GSM connection.

Comment: What about Android Access Control Enforcer? Could it be a solution? I could protect my applet against evil applications with well-chosen Access Rules, couldn't I?

Answer (score 1):

Targeting three of your questions:

1. Does it mean that the timer can fire the desired event even BEFORE it should?

   - **Normally, it wouldn't**. The quote from ETSI standards "The precision of the returned value cannot be relied upon in all cases due to potential terminal activities" actually means the mobile phone should trigger the timer event when the timer is up in the case that the phone is in idle state (for example, not in a phone call, or another STK session). So if the timer management is inaccurate, it's often delayed due to the busy state of the phone.
2. Is there any protection provided by OS against the timer event fraud (an attacker pretending the timer event has been fired)?

   - **No, there isn't.** For a sim card, there is no means for it to judge whether the terminal that it communicates with is a phone or a card reader. The attacker can always send pre-set commands from a card reader to attack the card and to fish information out of it as long as the commands are ISO7816-4 and GSM/UICC standards compliant.
3. Can I trust the timer even in some "serious" security applications, or is it just kind of a toy with a limited real world usage?

   - The issue does not lie in whether you should trust timer management sent from the terminal or not - reason being what i answered in question 2. If there is confidential or sensitive information contained in your timer management associated event, then you should implement a secure measure, for example, to encrypt the data. **May I ask what information you are trying to protect here?**

Comment: "May I ask what information you are trying to protect here?" - imagine a traffic app storing tickets on the SIM, which offer ticket buying offline (payed by electronic wallet on the SIM). Then the ticket is valid, if it was bought at least 60 seconds ago... So the applet would like to setup a timer for 60 seconds and then it would wait until the timer event is fired.

Comment: What about Android Access Control Enforcer? Could it be a solution? I could protect my applet against evil applications with well-chosen Access Rules, couldn't I?

Comment: According to what you said, the phone only provides a timer. When the timer is up, phone notifies the SIM about it. The processing of the tickets happens inside the SIM so I don't see you should be concerned about the security of the timer management.

Comment: "Android Access Control Enforcer" is a complete different set of solutions for another matter, that is for phone app to access the on-card java applet. So honestly, I am a bit confused here. If your ticketing solution involves a phone app, then you don't need to use Timer Management event. The phone app has easy access to get the system time and is able to notify the on-card applet to do something when time is up.

Comment: you can use java.util.Timer if it is an android phone app you are working on.